# How can I create an object with array using 1 Schema with mongoDB

Tags: angular, mongodb, express

I'm trying to create Author and Author's quote using 1 Schema

Here's my model for now:

```
  const mongoose = require("mongoose");


  const AuthorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      name: String,
      quote: Array


  module.exports = {
      Author: mongoose.model('Author', AuthorSchema)
  }
```

but Quote object should have validation like

```
quote: String
vote: Number
```

How can I achieve this using 1 Schema instead of 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just nest another object inside:

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

```
  const AuthorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      name: String,
      quote: [{quote: String, vote: Number}]


  module.exports = {
      Author: mongoose.model('Author', AuthorSchema)
  }
```